# How set variable with condition with immutable.js

Tags: immutable.js

This code in typescript:

```js
const b
if (a == true) {
   b = [1]
} else {
   b = [2]
}
```

how to convert above code to immutable.js ?

Comment: this typescript code does not compile for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

```js
let b
if (a) {
   b = List([1])
} else {
   b = List([2])
}

//or
const b = a ? List([1]) : List([2])
```